# Can't get Apache2 to run multiple Virtual hosts

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I made two files in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder. `site1` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.50:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName site1.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
</VirtualHost>
```

And `site2` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.50:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName site2.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/etc/hosts` I then added the following lines:

```
192.168.1.50    site1.local
192.168.1.50    site2.local
```

The output of `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` is:

```
site1  site2
```

But for both `http://site1.local` and `http://site2.local`, it opens up the same site.

Isn't Apache supposed to identify them through the `ServerName` directive? (which is different for the two sites). That's what the tutorials say that I've followed. Why doesn't it work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you configured the `NameVirtualHost` parameter in your httpd.conf file?  As I understand it, it's required for name-based virtual hosts - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: No, not previously. Now that I did, I have managed to get the second site to not show up at all, and the first site works fine. I have added `NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.50:80` in `httpd.conf` and at the beginning of both files in `sites-available`. As much as understood from that link, that is what I should have done?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it did work!